# MySQL добавить информацию в строку к уже имеющейся

Tags: mysql, python, flask, логирование

Собственно сабж

Если в базе, поле имеет текст 'text text text' как мне тогда добавить какую либо информацию в это поле что бы получилось например 'text text text information'

Т.е перезапись поля, думал сделать update, т.е получить уже имеющуюся информацию, дописать к ней нужные данные, и отправить обратно в базу, но меня смутила эта идея, т.к как это больше похоже на костыль.

А еще меня смутило то что может быть нагрузка сильная на базу, в этом поле будет хранится текст некий, который будет постепенно добавляться, большое кол-во текста. пример

[ID|TEXT]
1|text text text text text text
2|text2 text2 text2 text2 text2

Comment: Какую задачу решаете? Есть смутное подозрение что вы неправильно используете базу данных.

Comment: В своем случае я использую ее правильно, меня интересует как мне логировать действия пользователя без сторонних фреймворков, а просто неким простым решением логировать действия, которые совершил пользователь, не в txt же сохранять лог...

Comment: Обычно логирование делается как добавление записи в таблицу лога.  В дальнейшем и работать с этим проще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по комментариям есть задача логирования действий пользователя.

Насколько я могу судить на данный момент структура таблицы лога состоит из двух полей: идентификатор пользователя и некоторое текстовое поле, в которое планируется сливать все действия.

В этом случае запрос может быть вида

```
UPDATE log_table SET log = CONCAT(log, 'user action') WHERE id=1;
```

И в таблице будет столько записей, сколько пользователей. Но при этом поле с логом будет разрастаться и тормозит базу. А уже работать с таким логом - одно мучение.

Но правильней модифицировать таблицу и добавить в нее поле user_id и поле action_time типа DATETIME или TIMESTAMP.

И в этом случае логирование будет делаться запросом

```
INSERT INTO log_table (user_id, log, action_time) VALUES (1, 'user action', NOW())
```

В этом случае в таблице будет столько записей, сколько было всего действий. Но такой подход позволяет легко формировать любые статистические отчеты. Да и в случае каких-то проблем проще получить данные обычным SELECT, чем как-то доставать их из большого куска текста.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли мне, с первым вариантом, пожалуй на данный момент реализую его.

Comment: @CHBS да не вопрос. Welcome to India.